# In Pandas, how to group by column name and condition met, while joining the cells that met the condition in a single cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am having a hard time knowing how to even formulate this question, but this is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a pandas datatable with thousands of rows that look like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
```

| id | text | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | These are the | True | False |
| 2 | Values of "value1" | True | False |
| 3 | While these others | False | True |
| 4 | are the Values of "value2" | False | True |

How can I group by column name all the cells that met a condition while joining the cells that met the condition in a single cell to get a table that looks like this?

| values | merge_text |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | These are the Values of "value1" |
| value2 | While these others are the Values of "value2" |

I was thinking that to solve this, first I need to split the table into multiple tables containing the values that met the condition of a single column and then merge all the tables together.

```
v1 = df[['id', 'text', 'value1']]
v1 = v1[v1["value1"]==True]
```

| id | text | value1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | These are the | True |
| 2 | Values of "value1" | True |

```
v2 = df[['id', 'text', 'value2']]
v2 = v2[v2["value2"]==True]
```

| id | text | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | While these others | True |
| 4 | are the Values of "value2" | True |

What I do not know, and have failed to find the answer online, is how to merge the cells like this:

| values | merge_text |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | These are the Values of "value1" |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `set_index` with "id" and "text"; then `stack` `df`. Then (i) filter the Series by itself; (ii) `groupby` "value" and `join` "text":

```
s = df.set_index(['id','text']).stack()
out = s[s].reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=1)['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    index                                           text
0  value1               These are the Values of "value1"
1  value2  While these others are the Values of "value2"
```